# dreamweaver php mysql + profile page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, dreamweaver

hey guys i am creating a website with login and registration and profile page hat will be created by default as soon as the user register  in the form then log in these information will be displayed as a profile info in the profile page that is unique to each user. the username will specify each user and his profile page .these are some php files,
 anyone have an idea how to display the only the information that belong to the specified user and not all information of all  the users.

## registerForm.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">




<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Registration Page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>


<body>

<h2 class="RegisterTitleForm">Registration Form</h2>
<h3 class="requiredField">* Requierd Field!!</h3>
<table width="280" border="0" align="center">
<form action="registerProcess.php" method="post" id="registerForm">
  <tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" />
    <td style="text-align: right"><label for="firstname"><span class="Fields">First Name</span> <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align: right"><label for="lasttname" class="Fields">Last Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="birthdate">Birth Date</label></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="birthdate" value= "YYYY_MM_DD"  onfocus="if (this.value == 'YYYY_MM_DD') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'YYYY_MM_DD';}"  type="text" id="birthdate" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label></td>
    <td><input type="tel" name="phonenumber" value="000-0-000 000" onfocus="if (this.value == '000-0-000 000') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '000-0-000 000';}"  type="text"  id="phonenumber" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="gender">Gender <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
    <td><p>
      <label class="Fields">
        <input type="radio" name="genderGroup" value="Male" id="genderGroup_male" />
        Male</label>
      <br />
      <label class="Fields">
        <input type="radio" name="genderGroup" value="Female" id="genderGroup_female" />
        Female</label>
      <br />
    </p></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="country">Country</label></td>
    <td><select name="country" id="country"><option selected=>please choose coutry<option>lebanon<option>Us<option>europe 
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="adress">Local Adress <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="adress" id="adress" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="specialisation">Specialisation <span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
    <td><select name="specialisation" id="specialisation">
    </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="email">Email Adress<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
    <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></td>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="username">User Name<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="password">Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></td>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="Fields" style="text-align: right"><label for="password2">Re_Password<span class="requiredField">*</span></label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Register" /></td>
  </tr>
  </form>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

## registerprocess.php

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php'); 

  if(isset($_POST['register']))
{
  if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
  {
   $firstname = addslashes ($_POST['firstname']);
   $lastname = addslashes ($_POST['lastname']);
   $birthdate = addslashes ($_POST['birthdate']);
   $phonenumber = addslashes ($_POST['phonenumber']);
   $genderGroup = addslashes ($_POST['genderGroup']);
   $country = addslashes ($_POST['country']);
   $adress = addslashes ($_POST['adress']);
   $specialisation = addslashes ($_POST['specialisation']);
   $email = addslashes ($_POST['email']);
   $password2 = addslashes ($_POST['password2']);
   $username = addslashes ($_POST['username']);
   $password = addslashes ($_POST['password']);
   $password2 = addslashes ($_POST['password2']);
  }
  else
  {
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
   $birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
   $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
   $genderGroup = $_POST['genderGroup'];
   $country = $_POST['country'];
   $adress = $_POST['adress'];
   $specialisation = $_POST['specialisation'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];
   $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

  }


  $sql = "INSERT INTO users ".
       "(firstname,lastname, birthdate, phonenumber, gender, country, localadress, specialisation, email, username, password, password2, joindate) ".      "VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$birthdate','$phonenumber','$genderGroup','$country','$adress','$specialisation','$email','$username','$password','$password2', NOW())";

  $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
  if(! $retval )
  {
   die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo "Entered data successfully\n";

}
  mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

## loginForm.php

```
        <?php require_once('Connections/conn.php'); ?>
        <?php
        if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
        function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
        {
          if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
            $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
          }

          $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

          switch ($theType) {
            case "text":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
              break;    
            case "long":
            case "int":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
              break;
            case "double":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
              break;
            case "date":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
              break;
            case "defined":
              $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
              break;
          }
          return $theValue;
        }
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        // *** Validate request to login to this site.
        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
          session_start();
        }

        $loginFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        if (isset($_GET['accesscheck'])) {
          $_SESSION['PrevUrl'] = $_GET['accesscheck'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
          $loginUsername=$_POST['username'];
          $password=$_POST['password'];
          $MM_fldUserAuthorization = "";
          $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = "profileForm.php";
          $MM_redirectLoginFailed = "registerForm.php";
          $MM_redirecttoReferrer = false;
          mysql_select_db($database_conn, $conn);

          $LoginRS__query=sprintf("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s",
            GetSQLValueString($loginUsername, "text"), GetSQLValueString($password, "text")); 

          $LoginRS = mysql_query($LoginRS__query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
          $loginFoundUser = mysql_num_rows($LoginRS);
          if ($loginFoundUser) {
             $loginStrGroup = "";

            if (PHP_VERSION >= 5.1) {session_regenerate_id(true);} else {session_regenerate_id();}
            //declare two session variables and assign them
            $_SESSION['MM_Username'] = $loginUsername;
            $_SESSION['MM_UserGroup'] = $loginStrGroup;       

            if (isset($_SESSION['PrevUrl']) && false) {
              $MM_redirectLoginSuccess = $_SESSION['PrevUrl'];  
            }
            header("Location: " . $MM_redirectLoginSuccess );
          }
          else {
            header("Location: ". $MM_redirectLoginFailed );
          }
        }
        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        </head>
        <!--link CSS-->
        <link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <body>
        <!--<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>-->
              <div  id="loginForm"><table width="250" border="0" align="right">
          <form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="POST" action="<?php echo 

$loginFormAction; ?>">
            <tr>
              <td><label for="username">User Name</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Log In" />
                <a href="registerForm.php"><strong> Register</strong></a></td>
            </tr>
          </form>
        </table> 
        </div>
        <?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

## profileForm.php

Profile Page

```
<body>

<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>


    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    if(!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("testregister",$con);

    $username =(isset($_POST['username']));

    $result =mysql_query("Select * from users");

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<table border='0'>
    <tr>
    <td> First Name: </td>
    <td>" .$row['firstname'] ." </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Last Name: </td>
    <td>" .$row['lastname'] ." </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Birth Date: </td>
    <td>".$row['birthdate'] ." </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Phone Number: </td>
    <td> ".$row['phonenumber'] ." </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Gender: </td>
    <td> ".$row['gender'] ." </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Country: </td>
    <td>".$row['country'] ."</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Specialization: </td>
    <td>".$row['specialisation'] ."</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Email: </td>
    <td>".$row['email'] ."</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td> User Name: </td>
    <td>".$row['username'] ."</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td> Join Date: </td>
    <td>".$row['joindate'] ."</td>
    </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";


    mysql_close ($con);
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    Login Successful
    <p><a href="logout.php\">Click here to logout!</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean, how to only select from the database the user information of the user logined?

Comment: yes sir i tried the $result =mysql_query("Select * from users WHERE username='$username'");  this did not work.

Comment: Use the sessions :) Posted an answer of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$_POST['username']` for getting the username. It won't work.

You cannot pass a $_POST variable across two pages.You'll have to use sessions and pass the logged in username in a session variable and call it in your profile page.

For more information on session refer [this](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php)

Also
Use  `$result =mysql_query("Select * from users WHERE username='$username'");` instead of `$result =mysql_query("Select * from users");`

Comment: sir this solution did not work for me it not display anything

Answer (score 0):

in `registerprocess.php`

```
session_start() 
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

before

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users ".
```

and in `loginForm.php` ,change your sql query to mine

```
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$result =mysql_query("Select * from users where username=".$user."");
```

something like that, that is the logic, not the exact code...
HTH

Comment: sorry New Bee  i am new to php so can you explain exactly what these line do and how to use it properly in my code .thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, how to ONLY select the user logined from the database, do the following:

On the login file `loginForm`, create a session that keeps the user id or the username

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $loginUsername;
```

I can see that you already created a session variable called 'MM_Username', so, you can use that. I recommend to use the id of the row instead of the username.

Then, on the `profileForm` just select the row that matches the username with the query:

```
$the_query = mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='%s'",$_SESSION["MM_Username"]));
```

And that's all, remember the security in your database call! But that's another topic.
Good Luck!

(Remember to call `session_start()` first!)

`session_start()` "activates" the usage of the sessions and gets the session information. So it's important to call it before start using any $_SESSION

`$_SESSION` is a global variable that can be found in any php file, `$_SESSION["MM_Username"]` exists in all the php files, so you can use it on the `profileForm` for select that specific username.

Comment: Spamdark : session _start() where to use it in the profileForm .. because when i use it at the top it give me an error ( Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\Unnamed Site 2\resources\profileForm.php on line 14)  and the second error is ( Undefined variable: session_start in C:\wamp\www\Unnamed Site 2\resources\profileForm.php on line 14)  how to solve this and what it mean ?? thank you

Comment: Post the code with the session_start implemented please.
([pastebin](http://pastebin.com))

Comment: hey this it seam silly question but i am new here how can i post the new code  and thank you for your replies

Comment: Use an external website called pastebin ([pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com)), click on the 'create new paste' on the right menu in the top of the header. Paste your code, submit it, and give me the link in a comment.

Comment: ok sir this is the link [http://pastebin.com/6bmr6iNx]  hope that you can help me and thank you

Comment: `$session_start();`
the symbol `$` makes a reference to a variable, because `session_start()` is not a variable but a function, remove that `$` from `$session_start();`, only `session_start();`

Also it's better if you include it on the header.php or in the top of the page. Remember to use it whenever you are going to use `$_SESSION` (That includes `LoginForm.php`, you are using `$_SESSION` there too)

Comment: Another important topic, because you are not selecting all the users, and you are only selecting 1 user. The while loop is not really neccessary...

And, your query is insecure, it can be hacked with SQL Injection my friend, read more about [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or the newest one [mysqli::real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using mysqli instead of mysql. mysql is deprecated and won't last long anymore, while mysqli is the modern version of mysql.
more info: [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.php)